# Whats the difference between * and list() in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, pep448

I have noticed that some people use `*` to turn something into a list. I initially only knew of putting `list(x)` around the object, but doing `*x` also seems to work. Are they equivalent?

For example, both `*Counter(list).values()` and `list(Counter(list).values())` work fine

Comment: Well, `*Counter(list).values()` doesn't work by itself (you'd need `[*Counter(list).values()]` to make a `list`), but yes, they're equivalent (aside from `[*iterable]` *always* making a `list`, while `list(iterable)` can do anything if someone did a dumb and used `list` as a variable name, shadowing the `list` constructor).

Comment: You can read all about this on [PEP 448: Additional Unpacking Generalizations](https://peps.python.org/pep-0448/).